# Super key binding in emacs

Tags: emacs, key-bindings, emacs24

```
(global-set-key (kbd "<s-d>") 'duplicate-line)

;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;ECB MODE;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;
(global-set-key (kbd "<s-left>") 'ecb-goto-window-methods)
(global-set-key (kbd "<s-right>") 'ecb-goto-window-edit1)
(global-set-key (kbd "<s-down>") 'ecb-goto-window-history)
(global-set-key (kbd "<s-up>") 'ecb-goto-window-sources)
(global-set-key (kbd "<s-home>") 'ecb-goto-window-directories)
```

This is part of my .emacs file. I am facing a strange problem while binding a key combination containing `super` key. Whenever I bind a function to `super-key + <alphanumberic value>` it refuses to work.
In the above file all the bindings except `<s-d>` are working fine.
I am using emacs 24.3 on fedora 13

Comment: You need to use the vector notation (`[(super d)]`) as Andreas examples below.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The reason the `kbd` macro is so convenient is that the argument you pass it is exactly the same thing that Emacs tells you when you ask about a key binding. You're *guessing* at the argument, but you never need to do that.

When you type <kbd>C-h</kbd><kbd>k</kbd> (or <kbd>C-h</kbd><kbd>c</kbd>) and then the key sequence in question, Emacs will display a message describing that binding. In this instance it will describe super-key + d as `s-d`.

Therefore you can use `(kbd "s-d")` to refer to it.

- Ask Emacs to describe a key sequence
- Plug the answer into `kbd`

Answer (score 2):

Some selection which works here:

```
(global-set-key [(super ?\ö)] 'ar-beginning-of-comment-atpt)

(global-set-key [(super ?\Ö)] 'ar-end-of-comment-atpt)

(global-set-key [(super p)] 'View-sroll-line-backward)

(global-set-key [(super s)] 'hs-hide-all)

(global-set-key [(super tab)] 'scroll-up)

(global-set-key [(super \{)] 'ar-brace-region-atpt)

(global-set-key [(super space)] 'ar-whitespace-to-minus)

(global-set-key [(super kp-4)] 'missing-py-variable-name-face-lp-1215791-test)
```

Answer (score 2):

All of these are from `. . . /lisp/term/ns-win.el`

```
(define-key global-map [?\s-,] 'customize)
(define-key global-map [?\s-'] 'next-multiframe-window)
(define-key global-map [?\s-`] 'other-frame)
(define-key global-map [?\s-~] 'ns-prev-frame)
(define-key global-map [?\s--] 'center-line)
(define-key global-map [?\s-:] 'ispell)
(define-key global-map [?\s-?] 'info)
(define-key global-map [?\s-^] 'kill-some-buffers)
(define-key global-map [?\s-&] 'kill-this-buffer)
(define-key global-map [?\s-C] 'ns-popup-color-panel)
(define-key global-map [?\s-D] 'dired)
(define-key global-map [?\s-E] 'edit-abbrevs)
(define-key global-map [?\s-L] 'shell-command)
(define-key global-map [?\s-M] 'manual-entry)
(define-key global-map [?\s-S] 'ns-write-file-using-panel)
(define-key global-map [?\s-a] 'mark-whole-buffer)
(define-key global-map [?\s-c] 'ns-copy-including-secondary)
(define-key global-map [?\s-d] 'isearch-repeat-backward)
(define-key global-map [?\s-e] 'isearch-yank-kill)
(define-key global-map [?\s-f] 'isearch-forward)
(define-key global-map [?\s-g] 'isearch-repeat-forward)
(define-key global-map [?\s-h] 'ns-do-hide-emacs)
(define-key global-map [?\s-H] 'ns-do-hide-others)
(define-key global-map [?\s-j] 'exchange-point-and-mark)
(define-key global-map [?\s-k] 'kill-this-buffer)
(define-key global-map [?\s-l] 'goto-line)
(define-key global-map [?\s-m] 'iconify-frame)
(define-key global-map [?\s-n] 'make-frame)
(define-key global-map [?\s-o] 'ns-open-file-using-panel)
(define-key global-map [?\s-p] 'ns-print-buffer)
(define-key global-map [?\s-q] 'save-buffers-kill-emacs)
(define-key global-map [?\s-s] 'save-buffer)
(define-key global-map [?\s-t] 'ns-popup-font-panel)
(define-key global-map [?\s-u] 'revert-buffer)
(define-key global-map [?\s-v] 'yank)
(define-key global-map [?\s-w] 'delete-frame)
(define-key global-map [?\s-x] 'kill-region)
(define-key global-map [?\s-y] 'ns-paste-secondary)
(define-key global-map [?\s-z] 'undo)
(define-key global-map [?\s-|] 'shell-command-on-region)
(define-key global-map [s-kp-bar] 'shell-command-on-region)
;; (as in Terminal.app)
(define-key global-map [s-right] 'ns-next-frame)
(define-key global-map [s-left] 'ns-prev-frame)
```

Here is an example for ctrl+opt+command+s on a US Apple wired mini-keyboard:

```
(define-key global-map (kbd "<M-C-s-268632083>") 'help-for-help)
```