# Emacs - How can I find the code to use with kbd to identify a given key sequence

Tags: emacs

I'm being emacs user recently, When I bind a shortcut with a fun,eg:

```
(defun toggle-comment-on-line ()
  "comment or uncomment current line"
  (interactive)
  (comment-or-uncomment-region (line-beginning-position) (line-end-position)))

(global-set-key (kbd "\s /") 'toggle-comment-on-line)
```

I want use cmd+"/" to invoke this fun, but this not work.Searched for hours get nothing help

The Question is:

Where can I find aviliable kbd's document for emacs that I can search a symbol mapping from keyboard?  eg,what '/' stands for in kbd.

Comment: See also http://stackoverflow.com/a/19016163/324105 among others. It's effectively a duplicate, but this question was more generic, so I'm leaving it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To find the argument to pass to `kbd` you simply ask Emacs.

Type <kbd>C-h</kbd><kbd>k</kbd> (i.e. `describe-key`) and then the key(s) you are interested in, and Emacs tells you what to pass to `kbd`.

e.g. When I type <kbd>C-h</kbd><kbd>k</kbd> and then <kbd>Ctrl+x</kbd><kbd>space</kbd> Emacs tells me:

```
C-x SPC runs the command rectangle-mark-mode [...]
```

- This tells me that `C-x SPC` is how Emacs refers to <kbd>Ctrl+x</kbd><kbd>space</kbd>
- I therefore use `(kbd "C-x SPC")` to use that key sequence in elisp.

In your case, type <kbd>C-h</kbd><kbd>k</kbd> followed by <kbd>cmd+/</kbd> and then use whatever Emacs tells you.

You can alternatively use <kbd>C-h</kbd><kbd>c</kbd> (i.e. `describe-key-briefly`) to see the answer in the echo area.

Comment: Intuitive answer, Show me the key in bottom

Answer (score 1):

No special escape sequence is needed for '/'.  Your modifier keys need a different syntax however.  Since it sounds like you have an Apple keyboard the syntax you are probably looking for is:

```
(global-set-key (kbd "s-/") 'toggle-comment-on-line)
```

's' (lower-case) is for 'Super'.  If you wish to bind it to 'Control' use `C-/`.

**Advice for looking things up in emacs:**

In emacs you can look up the documentation for any function using `describe function`.  Type `C-h f` then `kbd` then `<Enter>`.

You can then read about the `kbd` function:

> kbd is a compiled Lisp function in `subr.el'.
>
> (kbd KEYS)
>
> Convert KEYS to the internal Emacs key representation. KEYS should be
>   a string constant in the format used for saving keyboard macros (see
>   `edmacro-mode').

Follow the link to edmacro-mode for detailed description of the syntax.

Comment: `S` is Shift. `s` is Super.

Comment: edmacro-mode describe is a little 'TLDR', I've followed your answer too test,It's an answer but not enough intuitive.